# MySQL & Form: Populate second select options based on first selected (From same row)

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

My problem is that I have three different stock sizes for each product that each contain a different amount of stock (large box, medium box, small box). Each product has the same box size but the quantity per box changes. When the product name is selected I want to then choose the box size and the quantity value should be set corresponding to the product row in the db.

```
------------------------------------------
|product      |small  |medium   |large   |
------------------------------------------
|Widget one   |100    |275     |400      |
------------------------------------------
|Widget two   |45     |100     |150      |
------------------------------------------
|Widget three |125    |150     |250      |
```

I already use php to get the select option product names from the db

```
    $product_select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");

    echo '<select name="Product" id="product">'; 
    while ($row_item = mysql_fetch_array($product_select)){ 
    $pname = $row_item["product"]; 
    echo '<option value="' . htmlspecialchars($pname) . '">' . htmlspecialchars($pname)    . '</option>';
```

Then I need something like this that gets the row values for small medium and large based on the selected product from above:

```
<select><option value=" ">Small</option><option value=" ">Medium</option><option value=" ">Large</option></select>
```

**EDIT**

I have been trying to figure this out all night. Is this even possible? should I just try and go a different route?

Comment: please, would you mind giving the involved tables structure? `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statement in mysql will return these informations.

Comment: @Sebas I chose to go with the option listed below using serialized values and jquery split function. This would seem to be the best way. Also the table structure is listed above in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 ways to  implement this:

1. Use Optgroup tags inside one select tag.
2. Use Ajax to get sizes and puplating second select after choosing product in the first select.
3. Store serialized values of stock inside first select and populate second select from that values.
   For example:

   ```
        <select>
        <option values="100|275|400">Widget one</option>
        ...
        </select>
   ```

Comment: I don't think optgroup tags would work because they aren't dynamic (atleast thats what I got from a google search). But I think #2 with ajax would work. Want to point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think, third way is better because it don't load the server by additional queries.

Comment: The third seems the most foreign to me because I have never worked with serialized values. I need to store the product 'Widget one' name and the stock value as well, with the serialize method it looks as if only the stock values would be submitted through the form.

Comment: I mean "serialized" - delimited by symbol "|" separator.

Comment: Yes, this would appear to be the best way to go about this. Thanks!